# Bigcommerce oauth2 authorization code request

Tags: node.js, api, oauth-2.0, bigcommerce

I am new to BigCommerce app development and I am struggling to develop my app using the oAuth2 authentication. I have just started the development of the app but I am struggling to figure out how I can test out the Auth Callback Request without having the app available in the Bigcommerce App store. Is there a way to mimic a merchant store installing my app and it sending the request to my apps Auth Callback URI? (Which then allows me to request the Access Token, etc, etc)

Is there a direct authorisation uri I can hit on the BigCommerce API to kick this off? (https://login.bigcommerce.com/oauth2/authorize)??

I will be developing the app in Node.js and the app will be using the Bigcommerce webhooks to receive orders made in my store, but i am falling at the first hurdle with authenticating my app with the store.

Kind regards

Comment: you have to follow de bigcommerce instruction in https://developer.bigcommerce.com/apps/

Comment: Got it. I had followed the instructions but couldn't see my draft app in the BigCommerce marketplace. But I didn't see the "My Drafts" app tab in the market place. All I did was to login to the trial store with the same email address used to register the app and it will appear in the My Draft apps in the market place.